# ES POSIBLE CAMBIAR LA VERSION DE PHP EN MI SERVIDOR DEBIAN SIN NECESIDAD DE CONECTARME POR SSH

Tags: php, debian, ssh, php8, laravel-9

Necesito instalar una versión de php en mi servidor Debian, lo lógico es hacerlo por SSH, pero no se si existe otra manera dado que actualmente por SSH va a ser imposible, no tengo la contraseña ni forma de generar una nueva, tengo acceso al panel de control del servidor y veo las carpetas de php que tengo instaladas pero se puede hacer este proceso sin utilizar una conexión SSH.

La página que requiere esta versión de PHP esta hecha en Laravel, utilizo XAMPP como host de desarrollo pero igualmente no he logrado cambiar la versión de php en XAMPP que quizás esa pueda ser otra opción dado que quiero cambiar la versión 8.1.12 a la versión 8.0.26, realizar un composer update a nivel local y si todo funciona subirla, teniendo un php superior y no tan lejano la página debería verse de nuevo. Las paso el error cuando subí la página:

*Composer detectó problemas en su plataforma: sus dependencias de
Composer requieren una versión de PHP ">= 8.1.12"*

Comment: Es mas fácil cambiar la versión de php en XAMPP sobre Windows que en Debian sin ssh. Ubica primero la versión de XAMPP que te sirve. Suena raro que composer requiera una versión tan alta, siendo que Laravel funciona con php >= 7.

Comment: Eso hice finalmente, te agradezco mucho tu respuesta, finalmente la página vuelve a verse, no se me habia ocurrido hacerlo así.